# Open url in existing browser process

Tags: 18.04

I've uninstalled and installed the default browser(chrome) trying to fix one problem. After this, when i press any url in another application, this page is opened in another process (i think as a child process) with same logo as application in which was opened, even if the browser is opened with some tabs.

An example is IntelliJ, I press an url, a browser is opened but with logo of IntelliJ. Same behavior with any app.

[image: Example case]

Comment: could you post a screenshot please?

Comment: I've added. If it is not clear i will change it. Thanks.